# shiny updateSelectizeInput return wrong value

Tags: r, shiny

I have code below with dependencies in `selectizeInput`. 
I'm trying to update both inputs but something going wrong and updating only first value
Any ideas? 
Thx for help

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
    ui <- navbarPage(
      title = "Interaction with Table Cells", id = "x0",

      tabPanel(
        "Table", DT::dataTableOutput("x1"),
        selectizeInput("s1", "speed", choices = cars %>% pull(speed) %>% unique()),
        uiOutput("s2")
      )
    )
    server <- function(session, input, output) {
      # add CSS style 'cursor: pointer' to the 0-th column (i.e. row names)
      output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(
          cars,
          selection = "none", class = "cell-border strip hover"
        ) %>% formatStyle(0, cursor = "pointer")
      })

      output$s2 <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput("s2", "dist", choices = cars %>% filter(speed == input$s1) %>%
          pull(dist) %>% unique())
      })

      observeEvent(input$x1_cell_clicked, {
        info <- input$x1_cell_clicked
        # do nothing if not clicked yet, or the clicked cell is not in the 1st column
        if (is.null(info$value) || info$col != 0) {
          return()
        }

        updateSelectizeInput(session, "s1", selected = cars[info$row, "speed"])
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "s2", selected = cars[info$row, "dist"])
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem with shiny's reactivity.

Its not true when you are saying only the first values gets updated. Its somewhat the opposite. s2 gets updated twice in the following order:

**First** after

```
updateSelectizeInput(session, "s2", selected = cars[info$row, "dist"])
```

is called.

**Second**, due to `input$s2` being dependent to the value of `input$s1` after `input$s1` was updated.

At the second time s2 is just dependent on all choices that are available with the current s1. Therefore the first value, not compelling the value chosen while calling `updateSelectizeInput(s2...)` is displayed.

To overcome this, you can create an reactive variable `values$s2_selected`, that stores the designated value for s2. We remove the second `updateSelectize` and just use the revalidation of s2 caused by the change of s1. And while doing so we use the stored designated selection as our selected option for s2.

**Example Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Interaction with Table Cells", id = "x0",

  tabPanel(
    "Table", DT::dataTableOutput("x1"),
    selectizeInput("s1", "speed", choices = cars %>% pull(speed) %>% unique()),
    uiOutput("s2")
  )
)
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  values<-reactiveValues()
  values$s2_selected<-""
  # add CSS style 'cursor: pointer' to the 0-th column (i.e. row names)
  output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      cars,
      selection = "none", class = "cell-border strip hover"
    ) %>% formatStyle(0, cursor = "pointer")
  })

  output$s2 <- renderUI({
    choices<-cars %>% filter(speed == input$s1) %>%
      pull(dist) %>% unique()
    if(isolate(values$s2_selected)%in%choices){
      selected=isolate(values$s2_selected)
    }
    else{
      selected<-choices[1]
    }
    selectizeInput("s2", "dist", choices = choices,selected=selected)
  })

  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_clicked, {
    info <- input$x1_cell_clicked
    # do nothing if not clicked yet, or the clicked cell is not in the 1st column
    if (is.null(info$value) || info$col != 0) {
      return()
    }
    values$s2_selected<-cars[info$row, "dist"]
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "s1", selected = cars[info$row, "speed"])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```